# Apex rest response: cyrillic characters encoding issue

Tags: api, webservices, rest, encoding

[**SOLVED**] Fixed in Spring Framework:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
.add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I have cyrillic characters in response.
**I prefer using void method with RestContext because I use HTTP error codes for errors.**

```
global class SalesOrder {
    global String name; //contains cyrillic letters
    ...
}
```

Works:

```
@HttpGet
global static SalesOrderWrapper getSalesOrder() {
    ...
    return salesOrder;    
}
```

Does not work (question marks instead of text):

```
@HttpGet
global static void getSalesOrder() {
    ...
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(salesOrder));
}
```

This does not help:

```
response.headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
response.headers.put('charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: How are you receiving your salesorder ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce your bug, may be you've missed something, or it's 3rd party problem. Please find my example below:

```
global class SalesOrder {
    global String name; //contains cyrillic letters
    public SalesOrder(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getSalesOrder() {
        SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder('Your name in Cyrillic here');
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(salesOrder));
    }
}
```

And what I've got in Postman:

[image: Cyrillic]

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue is not in salesforce. On the other side there is Spring Framework and RestTemplate. I think issue is here.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried with a basic example of Rest service and couldn't reproduce your issue. I am able to see the cyrillic characters in the workbench response. Can you please let me know how you are calling the Rest service?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account2/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        //return result;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(result.Name));
    }
}
```

[image]